# Webpack MUI5 Tree-Shaking

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, tree-shaking, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I would like to see a simple example of a react app with MUI5 and webpack where the tree-shaking works. (proof with webpack-bundle-analyzer) I would like to implement the same thing but somehow, I have not managed to achieve it. Is it possible? It can be that I have misunderstood something. Thank you in advance.

I have gone through this page: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/
but it did not help me.

with using imports like:

```
import createTheme, { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles/createTheme';
```

[mui-bundle-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMnxq.png)

Would it be possible achieve the same result with this import structure:

```
import { Theme, createTheme } from '@mui/material';
```

[mui-bundle-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q5dR.png)